# multithreading and classes?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is the issue that I'm having with multithreading. The proc needs to be static which means the only way I see that 2 threads can communicate and share data is through the global scope. This does not seem very clean nor does it feel very OO. I know I can create a static proc function in a class but that's still static.

What I'd like to for example do is have thread procs in the class somehow so that ex: I could create an MD5 checksum class and have an array of these objects, each on their own thread checking its hash, while the UI thread is not impaired by this and another class could simply keep track of the handles and wait for multiple objects before saying "Complete" or something. How is this limitation usually overcome?

Comment: Could you be more precise on your statement and then in your question? This so vague I have a hard time to figure out what assumptions about threading you are making (BTW threads come in several flavors, according to the OS), and even less what you really want to know. Why is this a C question?

Comment: Many inter-process communications (IPC) tools can be used between threads as well. Pipes, sockets, files. Each comes with costs and benefits. Time to do some reading...

Comment: I have taken away the C tag since the confusion in the answers shows that `static` in this question just means `static` member function in the sense of C++ and not a `static` symbol which confused all the guys looking for C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid using a static function if you want to start a thread there. You can however (using Windows) pass the this pointer as a parameter and use it on the other side to enter the class instance.

```
#include <windows.h>

class Threaded {
    static DWORD WINAPI StaticThreadEntry(LPVOID me) {
        reinterpret_cast<Threaded*>(me)->ThreadEntry();
        return 0;
    }

    void ThreadEntry() {
        // Stuff here.
    }

public:
    void DoSomething() {
        ::CreateThread(0, 0, StaticThreadEntry, this, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

Comment: you can avoid using a static function if you use Boost (which you should if you're programming in C++)

Comment: A static trampoline is definitely the way to go.  The *nix solution using pthread_create() is analogous.

Comment: @jalf Sometimes, Boost is just not available or add a heavy dependency in a project that is undesireable.

Comment: @jalf:  Some people can't use boost

Comment: True. But when you have the option, it is by far the cleanest solution. And unless otherwise specified, I assume that Boost *can* be used. (Calling it a "heavy" dependency always puzzles me though. Most Boost libs are pretty lightweight)

Comment: @jalf it's heavy for a current project I'm on in the sense that the cross-compiler isn't compatible. For us to address all of the compatibility issues would be very difficult.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, Boost.Thread solves the problem nicely. A thread is represented by a functor, meaning that the (non-static) `operator()` is the thread's entry point.

For example, a thread can be created like this:

```
// define the thread functor
struct MyThread {
  MyThread(int& i) : i(i) {}
  void operator()(){...}
private:
  int& i;
};

// create the thread
int j;
boost::thread thr(MyThread(j));
```

by passing data to the thread functor's constructor, we can pass parameters to the thread without having to rely on globals. (In this case, the thread is given a reference to the integer `j` declared outside the thread.)

With other libraries or APIs, it's up to you to make the jump from a (typically static) entry point to sharing non-static data.

The thread function typically takes a (sometimes optional) parameter (often of type `void*`), which you can use to pass instance data to the thread.

If you use this to pass a pointer to some object to the thread, then the thread can simply cast the pointer back to the object type, and access the data, without having to rely on globals.

For example, (in pseudocode), this would have roughly the same effect as the Boost example above:

```
void MyThreadFunc(void* params) {
  int& i = *(int*)params;
  ... 
}

int j;
CreateThread(MyThreadFunc, &j);
```

Or the parameter can be a pointer to an object whose (non-static) member function you wish to call, allowing you to execute a class member function instead of a nonmember.

Comment: To me, this is not solving the problem. It's the same exact problem packaged differently, because the instance data is still passed in through void *. What is the benefit? All that happens is that you've added another class to the hierarchy. This is a good portability solution, but it has little to do with the question at hand. Or am I missing something that lets you instantiate the thread and directly operate on the data?

Comment: @San Jacinto: the OP assumed the only solution is to share data allocated in global scope. A `void*` passed as a parameter to the thread is not global, so it solves the OP's problem. What's more, the Boost solution preserves type safety too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood well... I give it a try. Are you looking for [thread local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) ?

Answer (score 0):

Thread creation routines usually allow you to pass a parameter to the function which will run in a new thread.  This is true for both Posix pthread_create(...) and Win32 CreateThread(...).  Here is a an example using Pthreads:

```
void* func (void* arg) {
    queue_t* pqueue = (queue_t*)arg;

    // pull messages off the queue
    val = queue_pull(pqueue);

    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread;
    queue_t queue = queue_init();

    pthread_create(&thread, 0, func, &queue);

    // push messages on the queue for the thread to process
    queue_push(&queue, 123);

    void* ignored;
    pthread_join(&thread, &ignored);

    return 0;
}
```

No statics anywhere.  In a C++ program you could pass a pointer to an instance of a class.

Comment: This is true, but you being to pollute the namespace (in your case the global namespace). This is why a static member function is preferred. By using one, you have a mechanism equal to what you describe without the namspace problems it creates.

Comment: If you like creating classes for everything, that's fine.  In C++, you could easily wrap the thread function in a namespace if that's your bag.  To my taste, it's six or a half dozen.